# Use "this" to call a function

Tags: javascript

When I try to use "this" to call a function, an error occured saying :"this.slideshow_action is not a function". Can you please let me know my fault!?

```
var class_slider = {
        current_slide: 0, //Starting Slide
        total_slides: 4, //All Slides
        slideshow_action: function(slide_number) {
            $(".slide_text").hide();
            $(".main_navigation_container").removeClass("selected");
            $("#slide_" + slide_number).addClass("selected");
            $("#slide_" + slide_number + "_text").fadeIn("slow");
        },
        slideshow: function() {
            if (this.current_slide === this.total_slides)
                this.current_slide = 0;//Make a new tour
            else
                this.current_slide++;
           this.slideshow_action(this.current_slide);
        },
        reset_timer: function()
        {
            window.clearInterval(this.slideshow_timer);
            this.slideshow_timer = window.setInterval(this.slideshow, 5000);
        },
        icon_action: function(element) {
            this.reset_timer();
            var arr = element.attr("id").split('_'); //Get Last Part of id(slide number)
            this.current_slide = parseInt(arr[1]); //Get slide Number
            this.slideshow_action(this.current_slide);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Ok so where have you defined that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function class_slider(){

  var that = {
    current_slide: 0, //Starting Slide
    total_slides: 4, //All Slides
    slideshow_action: function(slide_number) {
        $(".slide_text").hide();
        $(".main_navigation_container").removeClass("selected");
        $("#slide_" + slide_number).addClass("selected");
        $("#slide_" + slide_number + "_text").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    slideshow: function() {
        if (that.current_slide === that.total_slides)
            that.current_slide = 0;//Make a new tour
        else
            that.current_slide++;
       that.slideshow_action(that.current_slide);
    },
    reset_timer: function()
    {
        window.clearInterval(that.slideshow_timer);
        that.slideshow_timer = window.setInterval(that.slideshow, 5000);
    },
    icon_action: function(element) {
        that.reset_timer();
        var arr = element.attr("id").split('_'); //Get Last Part of id(slide number)
        that.current_slide = parseInt(arr[1]); //Get slide Number
        that.slideshow_action(that.current_slide);
    }
  };

  return that;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use contexts.

```
setTimeout(function(context){
        context._someMethod();
    }, 5000, this);
}

var timer = setInterval(function(context){
        context._someMethod();
    }, 5000, this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the setInterval call like so:

```
this.slideshow_timer = window.setInterval(this.slideshow.bind(this), 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You run `this.slideshow` from `setInterval` that is why context is wrong.
You can `bind` function to the context, use jQuery `proxy`,  use `that = this` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're seeing this is because the `this` in your context is not the `this` you're expecting. Let me explain why.

In JavaScript there's something called the executing context (or that's how I like to refer to it). When a function is called, it's called within a context. Like, for example, when you have an instance of a object the object is the context:

```
var MyObject = function(){};
MyObject.prototype.myFunction = function() {};
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myFunction();
```

When you call the myFunction method the context for that method is `myObject`. If you'd pass this method to the `setTimeout` method it has no clue as to which object `myFunction` belongs. Internally it calls it like this `theAssignedVariable.call(this);`. `this` in that context is something totally different (window in most cases). So what you're basically seeing is `slideshow_action` being called on `window` (this).

To get around issues like this would be do something like:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() { 
  _this.callSomeFunction();
}, 1000);
```

In javascript there's also a `bind` method on `Function`. On the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) they explain how you use this.

The other answers to your question are valid, but none of them explain why it doesn't work.